# Search results in a table cause out of place data in table.

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello guys I'm having trouble with this script I made. Any time I use the search bar to search for data on my website in a table form the first row always come back perfectly with the data in tact but any thing after the first row all the data falls out of place in the other rows. I was able to do this perfectly in non-table structure situations so I don't know why this is doing this I need help how I can keep all the data intact.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgNfR.png)

```
    <?php 
//SEARCHX
include("hidden_path/mysqli/procedural/session/session_crud/v1/0/instructions/php/session_and_connection.php");
$output = ' ';

if(isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] !== ' ') {
$user_input = $_GET['search'];


if ($user_input === "") {
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
die;
}

//PAGINATION
$user_input = $_GET['search'];
$and = "&";


$pagevx = "page=";

//SEARCHX
$user_input = trim(" $user_input ");

$user_input = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $user_input);

$user_input = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $user_input);

$user_input = htmlspecialchars($user_input);

//PAGINATION
$page =  mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$user_input%' OR post_content LIKE '%$user_input%'");
// total row count
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($page);
$rows = $row[0];
// results displayed per page
$page_rows = 2;
// page number of last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
// makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1) {
$last = 1;
}
// page num
$pagenum = 1;
// get pagenum from URL if it is present otherwise it is 1
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
$pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
}
// makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more then our $last page
if($pagenum < 1) {
$pagenum = 1;
}
else if($pagenum > $last) {
$pagenum = $last;
}
// set the rage of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
$limit = 'LIMIT ' . ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows . ',' . $page_rows;
$page = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$user_input%' OR post_content LIKE '%$user_input%' ORDER BY post_id DESC $limit");



// establish $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// if more the 1 page
if($last != 1) {
if($pagenum > 1) {
$previous = $pagenum - 1;
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'. $row["post_title"].'?search='.$user_input.$and.$pagevx.$previous.'"><span class="pag_back_arrow"; style="text-decoration: none;"><</a></span> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
// Render clickable number links
for($i = $pagenum - 4; $i < $pagenum; $i++) {
if($i > 0) {
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'. $row["post_title"].'?search='.$user_input.$and.$pagevx.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
}
}
}
// render the target page number without a link
$paginationCtrls .= ''. $pagenum . ' &nbsp; ';
// render clickable number links that appear on the right
for($i = $pagenum + 1; $i < $last; $i++) {
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'. $row["post_title"].'?search='.$user_input.$and.$pagevx.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
// allows up to 4 pages
if($i >= $pagenum + 4) {
break;
}
}
if($pagenum != $last) {
$next = $pagenum + 1;
$paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; <a href="'. $row["post_title"].'?search='.$user_input.$and.$pagevx.$next.'"><span class="pag_next_arrow"; style="text-decoration: none;">></a></span> ';
}
}

//SEARCHX

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
Results
</title>

</head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="0/instructions/css/query/desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="0/instructions/css/query/mobile.css">

<body>



<?php
//SEARCHX
$c = mysqli_num_rows($page);
if($c == 0) {
$output = '<h2 class="no_results_error_message";><span style="color: red;">No results for: </span><b><span style="color: white;">' . $user_input . '</span></h2></b>';


}  else {

?>


<div class="result_section";>
<h2><span class="for_headline">Results For: </span><span id="result_output"><?php $outputx = "$user_input"; print("$outputx"); ?></span></h2>
</div>


<!-- Search Box -->
<?php include("search_box.php"); ?> <br>

<table width='80%' border=0>
<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
<td>user_id</td>
<td>topic_id</td>
<td>post_title</td>
<td>post_content</td>
<td>post_date</td>
<td>Update</td>
</tr>

<?php

// shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
$textline1 = "Search_i";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($page, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {     
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['user_id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['topic_id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['post_title']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['post_content']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['post_date']."</td>";

echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?post_id=$row[post_id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?post_id=$row[post_id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td></table>";       

?>

<?php

$output .= '<a href="' . $link . '">

</a>';


}
}
} else {
header("location: ./");
}

print("$output");

mysqli_close($connect);

?>

<!-- PAGINATION -->
<!--shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages -->
<p><?php //echo $textline1 = "Search_i"; ?></p>
<p id="page_of";><?php //echo $textline2; ?></p>

<div class="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are closing table in loop. Change your code with

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($page, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['user_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['topic_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_content'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_date'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?post_id=$row[post_id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?post_id=$row[post_id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td></tr>";
}
</table> //close table after loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply urfusion but I done that before in the past it would give me this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in etc.. on line 175". So in other words if you look at the code you see that there is additional curly brackets down below enough to close the loop. so the code is error free the way it is now, but I hate that it projects the out of place data in the table like that like I said I never had this problem in other non-table situations before i'm referring to the pagination and the search code. What else do you think it could be the problem with this code?

Comment: I think I fixed it its strange how code works It works in different ways so this is what I did I removed the ending table tag *</table> and it worked so then I said well I don't feel right about doing that. So then I put the table ending tag aka </table> all the away below on top of where it said <!-- PAGINATION --> and bingo it worked!!!! So yeah it seems like I fixed it but thanks for your response tho .